# Woocommerce Checkout Page - Show Product Description but Exclude One Product Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently using the porto theme on wordpress with woocommerce, and it doesn't have an option to show the product description in the mini cart or checkout page.  I was able to find the following css code to add that worked, but I'm trying to limit this to display the product descriptions for most products while excluding only items from one specific category slug.

For example, we have cart items and would like the description to be hidden only for the pats in that one category 'carts'. Here's the code I found that blanket worked for every product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function customizing_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description(); // Get the product description

    // For product variations when description is empty
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 && empty( $description ) ){
        // Get the parent variable product object
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        // Get the variable product description
        $description = $parent_product->get_description();
    }

    // If product or variation description exists we display it
    if( ! empty( $description ) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'key'      => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'    => $description,
            'display'  => $description,
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

Does anyone have a recommendation? Thanks in advance I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just insert the following in the function before processing anything else:

```
    if ( has_term( 'your-slug', 'product_cat', $cart_item ) ) {

       return $cart_data ; 

    }
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/